# Excel 2003 zooming

Tags: vba, excel, zooming

I have a trouble with a Excel document. I need set a specific zoom to show the full content of my sheet. The trouble is that I must distribute this document in different computers with different resolution. Then, I cann't work with an specific zoom value, this value must be dynamic.

I tried this:

```
With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
 .FitToPagesTall = 1
 .FitToPagesWide = 1
 .Zoom = False
End With
```

But this don't work, at least in Excel 2003.

I also tried with ActiveWindow.Zoom but I think with this library I won't be able to fit the zoom to the page.

There are my questions:
1. How can I fit the zoom to the page content?
2. Is there an option to do it without VB?

My main problems are:
1. Showing the document in different resolutions.
2. Opening the document in different Excel versions (2003, 2007 and maybe 2013).

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If you select a range and then set the Zoom to True, it will fit to the selection, so:

```
Sub FitIt()
    Dim rgToFit               As Range
    Dim rgCurrent             As Range

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set rgCurrent = ActiveCell

    ' CHANGE THIS TO WHATEVER RANGE YOU WANT
    Set rgToFit = ActiveSheet.UsedRange

    rgToFit.Select
    ActiveWindow.Zoom = True
    rgCurrent.Select
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```